# SVN: Change location of externals files, now can't access in Eclipse

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I recently had to change the IP Address on our SVN server. I switched the repository to the new IP Address without any problems and I edited the location of the my external folder using the following command:

```
svn propedit svn:externals .
```

But in Eclipse I can check out everything except the external folder.

I'm not sure what's going on, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solved it. The problem was with eclipse, it still had a reference to the old IP Address.

So to change it, right click on the project folder in Eclipse, hover over Team, click on Show Properties, then you should see the reference to the external folder. Edit this reference with the correct value.

Then update the project, and it should pull in the external folder.